# Roots of digamma function in R

Tags: r, statistics, numerical-methods, mle, gamma-function

I am working on a maximum likelihood estimator, and one of the parameters is estimated using the digamma function.  I'm trying to use uniroot to solve the equation but am unable to do so.  Here's my code:

```
dig = function(alpha){
    digamma(2 + alpha) - digamma(alpha) - (1/(2+alpha)) + (2/(2+alpha))
}

curve(dig, from = 0, to = 10)
uniroot(dig, lower = 0, upper = 10)
```

This produces the following error:

```
Error in uniroot(dig, lower = 0, upper = 10) : f.lower = f(lower) is NA
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In digamma(alpha) : NaNs produced
2: In digamma(alpha) : NaNs produced
```

The first error sort of makes sense based on the curve, but the second has me stuck. It's entirely possible that I'm misunderstanding how to find the roots of the digamma function, or that there's a numerical package (maybe rootsolve?) in R that could help. Not sure what I'm missing here- any tips would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: `gamma(0)` is not defined.

Comment: ...and also your  `dig(0)` returns `NaN`. From the curve, it's pretty clear that there isn't any root in in the (0,10] interval, so don't get why you are using `uniroot`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following

```
curve(dig, from = 0.01, to = 10)
uniroot(dig, lower = 0.01, upper = 10)
```

[image]

> Error in `uniroot(dig, lower = 0.01, upper = 10)` : 
>     `f()` values at end points not of opposite sign

Comment: MichaelChirico, thanks for this example- I should have checked my function more closely.  I find that dig has roots in the intervals (-1, 0) and (0, +Inf). Is there a way to pass open intervals to uniroot?

Comment: Just run it on the intervals separately

Comment: @sqlck Can you explain why dig has a root on (0, +inf)? I'm not understanding it. I do see the one on (-1, 0).

Comment: @RobertDodier I'm not saying it does; I'm saying the root-search problem on two intervals can be split into two separate root search problems

Comment: @RobertDodier, you're right- sorry about that.  There is a root on (-1,0), and two roots on (0, +inf).  I used this code:                                               `curve(dig, from = -1.5, to = 10); abline(h = 0, lty = 3);`